# Customisable countdown app

Tags: ios, time-management

Can anyone recommend a daily countdown app which allows certain days (e.g. Fridays, weekends and UK public hilodays) to be excluded, then displays the countdown result in the app icon?

It doesn't have to be free.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick selection:

[Gestimer](http://maddin.io/gestimer/)

[image: Gestimer]

[Tyme](http://tyme-app.com/mac-2/)

[image: Tyme]

[menubarcountdown](http://capablehands.net/menubarcountdown)

[image: http://capablehands.net/menubarcountdown]

[Vitamin-R](http://www.publicspace.net/Vitamin-R/)
[image: Vitamin-R]

[Pomodoro](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/31472/pomodoro)
[image: Pomodoro]

Comment: The question is tagged with iOS not macOS